# ngx-bootstrap modal cannot read property 'show' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal, ngx-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement ngx-bootstrap modal in my angular app. But it gives me an error saying **Cannot read property 'show' of undefined**.

**Modal HTML**

`

```
<div *ngIf="isActive" bsModal #createOrEditAuthorModal="bs-modal" 
class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">

      ............

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`

**Modal Ts**

`

```
export class CreateOrEditAuthorModalComponent extends 
AppComponentBase {
  @ViewChild('createOrEditAuthorModal') public modal: 
  ModalDirective

  isActive = false;

  constructor(
    injector: Injector
  ) {
    super(injector);
    this.author = new UpdateAuthorInput();
  }

  show(): void {
    this.modal.show();
    this.isActive = true;
  }

  close(): void {
    this.modal.hide();
    this.isActive = false;
  }

}
```

`

**Parent Component HTML**

`

```
<app-create-or-edit-author-modal #createOrEditAuthor></app-create- 
or-edit-author-modal>
```

`

**Parent Component Ts**

`

```
export class AuthorsComponent extends AppComponentBase implements 
AfterContentInit {
  @ViewChild('createOrEditAuthor') createOrEditAuthor: 
CreateOrEditAuthorModalComponent

  constructor(
    injector: Injector
  ) {
    super(injector);
  }

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {

  }

  createNewAuthor(): void {
    this.createOrEditAuthor.show();
  }

}
```

`

[image]

Don't know where is the problem though everything seems okay. It worked yesterday but giving error today. please any body help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removing `*ngIf="isActive"` resolves the problem